# How to change Code analysis error CA1506 class coupling to "moderate maintainability"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, roslyn-code-analysis

I get this code analysis error for class coupling. The error message says:

> 'xxxxx' is coupled with 32 different types from 12 different
>   namespaces. Rewrite or refactor the method to decrease its class
>   coupling, or consider moving the method to one of the other types it
>   is tightly coupled with. A class coupling above 40 indicates poor
>   mainainability, a class coupling **between 40 and 30 indicates
>   moderate maintainability**, and a class coupling below 30 indicates good
>   maintainability.

Currently I get this error because it is trying to enforce a "... below 30 indicates good maintainability".
Now I would like to change that to a "moderate maintainability", which I can have upto 40 class coupling and no more.

Now how do I change this?
I search all over and couldn't find how to change this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is configurable. I'd strongly recommend simplifying your code. If you really don't want to do that, you can suppress the warning on specific types with

```
#pragma warning disable CA1506

// My type

#pragma warning restore CA1506
```

Comment: I finally had to simplify my code. As you said, there is only enable or disable, no changing the level. Thanks